# ESLint importing react

Tags: reactjs, eslint, jsx

I'm using eslint and getting this error because of `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` on a bunch of stuff inc react, chai, react-dom etc

`'react' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S react' to add it`

In my package.json I have the following ('...' represents other packages that don't seem relevant):

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    ...
 },
```

I have a package.json in the root of my project but I also have individual package.json files for each of my components. Is there a way for it to reference the root file dependency or do I have to add it to all the individual component package.json files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't an option to reference a parent `package.json` (see also [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8112)), because `npm` assumes self-contained, independent packages.

So if you want to get it working properly, you'll have to list *all* dependencies for each component in their respective `package.json` file, basically making each component an independent package.

That, or work around the reason why you need separate `package.json` files for each component.

Comment: This is what I have done! But it wants me to move chai into dependancies not devdependancies which seems incorrect to me as the tests wont be run on production.

Comment: Yeah, `chai` would be a dev dependency in my book as well. I'd look into making ESlint shut up about it ;D

Comment: Ha ha! Turns out i just had to add mocha as a plugin and then set the environment in eslint! Success!